# sympy cannot integrate sqrt(tan(x))

Tags: python, sympy

`sympy` returns just the integral symbol without solving it.

```
from sympy import tan, sqrt,symbols, integrate
x=symbols('x')
integrate(sqrt(tan(x)))
```

The thing is that WolframAlpha, Maxima, and symbolab would solve the integral.
Why `sympy` cannot do it?

Comment: please provide all your imports (or if this assumes `from sympy import *`) and also how you created `x`!

Answer (score -2):

Is this the problem?

```
from sympy import tan, sqrt, integrate, symbols

x = symbols('x', real = True)
integrate(sqrt(tan(x)))

# output:
Integral(sqrt(tan(x)), x)
```

`sympy` returns the `Integral` object when it cannot solve a particular integral. If other tools can do it, that's because they are more powerful tools.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. All you've shown is that the integral of a constant value from 0 to 1 is that value.

Comment: Hm, try `sympy.ntegrate(x**2)`.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg's point might be that your first statement, "specify the interval, otherwise you will receive a result containing the dummy symbol", is wrong. Sympy can compute indefinite integrals (beware that it will not include the constant).

Comment: @jared Exactly.

Comment: Ok, I thought a bit about his problem and rewrote the  answer.